# Second click on canvas is not being fired on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, canvas

I have a candy-crush like game and use this four listeners to swap items

```js
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown); // also tried pointerup and pointerdown
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseOut);
```

It works perfectly on desktop, but sometimes second click (mousedown) (on second tile is not being fired at all). I mean listener function is not being called.
I have

```css
cursor: pointer
```

in my CSS and I don't know what to do.

Note: If you click next time somewhere on canvas, event is being triggered as if it was clicked in the old spot.
So if I what to change places of tiles x: 0, y: 0 and x: 0, y: 1:

1. I select first tile (x: 0, y: 0)
2. I try to select second tile (x:0, y:1). Event is not being triggered
3. If I click on any random tile those two will swap places somehow

Help please! Thanks!

Comment: Try using "touchstart" on mobile instead of "mousedown" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Touch Events [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) in conjunction with your existing code

```js
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', onMouseDown);
canvas.addEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp);
```

Comment: I don't want to be impolite, but could you please check out my new related question? [Mobile devices touch event is not being triggered as many times as I clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70265249/mobile-devices-touch-event-is-not-being-triggered-as-many-times-as-i-clicked). You answer helped to get better performance, but there is new problem and I can't figure it out. Some how touch event is not being triggered as many times as I have clicked the screen